# Regex Not Finding both Matches

Tags: regex

I have this regex expression `(:[^\s])|(nh:)` for string **nh:Nursing Home Name**

I am trying to return `nh:` and also `:`

The expression will only return one match (`nh:` or `:`) when the other pattern is removed but not both.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Edit: Update with Code

```
Public Class regEntry
        Property mask As String
        Property format As textFormat
        Property customFormat As String = String.Empty
        Property MaskType As regtype
        Property manualIndex As Integer = 0
    End Class

  If library.Any(Function(x) x = Formatter.Library.General) Then
            General.AddRange({
         New regEntry With {.mask = "['][a-z][a-z]{1}", .format = textFormat.Upper, .MaskType = regtype.Reg, .manualIndex = 1},
         New regEntry With {.mask = "[\s][m][a][c][a-z]{1}", .format = textFormat.Upper, .MaskType = regtype.Reg, .manualIndex = 4},
         New regEntry With {.mask = "\s(of)\s", .format = textFormat.Lower, .MaskType = regtype.Reg, .manualIndex = 1},
         New regEntry With {.mask = "[\s][m][c][a-z]{1}", .format = textFormat.Upper, .MaskType = regtype.Reg, .manualIndex = 3},
         New regEntry With {.mask = ":", .format = textFormat.Custom, .customFormat = ": ", .MaskType = regtype.Reg},
            New regEntry With {.mask = "nh:", .format = textFormat.Upper, 
.MaskType = regtype.Text}})

            _masterlist.AddRange(General.ToArray)
        End If


Public Function formatText(textString As String) As String
        Dim FoundText As String
        Dim t As String = textString.Trim()
        Dim matches As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(t.ToLowerInvariant(), _masterReg, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
        Dim sb As New StringBuilder(StrConv(t, VbStrConv.ProperCase))
        Dim sb As New StringBuilder(t)

        For Each match As RegularExpressions.Match In matches
            For Each capture As RegularExpressions.Capture In match.Captures
                If _masterlist.Any(Function(x) x.mask = capture.Value
                                   ) Then
                    Dim re = _masterlist.Find(Function(x) x.mask = capture.Value)
                    If re.format <> textFormat.Custom Then
                        FoundText = t.ToString.ToString.Substring(capture.Index, capture.Length).ToUpper()
                        sb.Remove(capture.Index, capture.Length).Insert(capture.Index, formattedString(FoundText, re.format))
                    Else
                        sb.Remove(capture.Index, 1).Insert(capture.Index, re.customFormat)

                    End If
                Else
                    Dim sec = _masterlist.Where(Function(x) x.MaskType = regtype.Reg)

                    For Each reg In sec.ToList
                        Dim matchesagain As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(t.ToLower, reg.mask)
                        For Each match2 As RegularExpressions.Match In matchesagain
                            For Each capture2 As RegularExpressions.Capture In match2.Captures

                                If reg.format = textFormat.Custom Then
                                    sb.Remove(capture2.Index, capture2.Length).Insert(capture2.Index, reg.customFormat)
                                Else
                                    FoundText = t.ToString.Substring(capture2.Index, capture2.Length)
                                    If reg.manualIndex <> 0 Then
                                        Dim transtext = FoundText.Remove(reg.manualIndex, 1).Insert(reg.manualIndex, formattedString(FoundText.Substring(reg.manualIndex, 1), reg.format))
                                        sb.Remove(capture2.Index, capture2.Length).Insert(capture2.Index, transtext)
                                    Else
                                        sb.Remove(capture2.Index, capture2.Length).Insert(capture2.Index, reg.customFormat)
                                    End If
                                End If
                            Next
                        Next
                    Next
                End If
            Next
        Next
        Return sb.ToString
    End Function
```

This code performs operations on strings to ensure that they are well formatted according to the criteria we set. Like capitalizing certain phrases or changing words to proper case.

Comment: `(?=((?:nh)?:))`? See https://regex101.com/r/RV56tI/1

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to separate them into two separate patterns as these are part of a larger regex concatenate and with each pattern we perform a separate string operation.

Comment: Please edit the question to explain your *real* issue.

Comment: Updated with code.